# Enable Camera Pano mode with Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-plugin

Is there a way to enable the panoramic mode of the camera both on Android and ios with Flutter camera plugin? Couldn't find any documentation or code around it (neither in the source).

Is it something planned?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

answer of 2019-08-12 
Is it something planned? 
Camera Plugin is under Refactor/Rework) 
panoramic mode did not include in this Milestone. 
You can trace here 
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/31225#issuecomment-516091146

Support Android Camera 16+ 
Support iOS Camera 8.0+ 
Camera Orientation Control 
Video/Preview/Picture output sizes 
Android Pause and Resume video recording (MediaRecorder) 
Zoom Control 
Flash 
Automatic Exposure 
Permission Handling (Camera/Audio) 
Auto Focus 
Memory Leak 
Provide Complex Camera Example 
Expand Controls over video and image formats 
Direct access to image buffer when taking a photo

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will follow this milestone and create a "wish" github issue.

Comment: @Vlad is there any update for enabling the panoramic mode of the camera both on Android and ios with Flutter

Comment: Hey, I'm really sorry but I didn't have time to continue my app - I will soon be back to it, I'll check. But as @chunhunghan said, there is still a task on their side: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/31225